Error while deploying solidity contracts using HardHat
So i catch so many errors including the Pragma solidity version i am using which is
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
and another error :
Source
"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File not found. 
Searched the following locations: "/Users/../DecentralizedStorage/.",
"/Users/../DecentralizedStorage/node_modules", 
"/Python312/Lib/site-packages/wake/contracts"

I did install the library in my project.
i installed the library and it should accept the import but it didn't

Can you share your package.json ?

I solved the problem and the solution is that you need to export the ABI in a single folder and work with that ,
